# How to create a rule that passes only the Request Path - urlrewritefilter

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Since we use ajax in our pages, We need to serve search bots requests from our Ajax Prerender service.

To do that I created a rule to modify crawling requests. 
`<OUR_DOMAIN>/stocks?_escaped_fragment_=` is converted to `http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f/stocks`

I used the following rule:

```
<rule>
        <name>escaped_fragment</name>
        <!--<condition type="request-filename" operator="notfile"/>-->
        <condition type="query-string" operator="equal">.*escaped_fragment.*</condition>
        <from>(.*)$</from>
        <to type="proxy" last="true" qsappend="true">http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/TOKEN_e291b9f78$1</to>
    </rule>
```

**The Problem** is that it generates a wrong URL: `http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f/stockshttp://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f`.

Would love to get advice on how to build the rule correctly.

I am using urlrewritefilter - 4.0.3

**Log:**

```
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.u.ServerNameMatcher | looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.UrlRewriteFilter    | checking for status path on /stocks
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter| processing request for /stocks
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.urlrewrite.RuleBase   | escaped_fragment (rule 0) run called with /stocks
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.urlrewrite.RuleBase   | matched "from"
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.urlrewrite.Condition  | evaluating "_escaped_fragment_=" against .*escaped_fragment.*
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.urlrewrite.RuleBase   | conditions match
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.s.MatcherReplacer   | found 1
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.s.MatcherReplacer   | replaced sb is http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f/stocks
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.s.MatcherReplacer   | found 1
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.s.MatcherReplacer   | replaced sb is http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RuleExecutionOutput | needs to be 
proxied from http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f/stockshttp://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f
DEBUG|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter| rule is last
 INFO|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RequestProxy        | execute, 
target is http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f/stockshttp://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/MY_TOKEN_e291b9f
 INFO|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RequestProxy        | response commit state: false
 INFO|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RequestProxy        | checking url
 INFO|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RequestProxy        | seting up the host configuration
 INFO|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RequestProxy        | config is HostConfiguration[host=http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com]
 INFO|http-apr-8080-exec-2|o.t.w.f.u.RequestProxy        | setting proxy request parameter:connection, value: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like a bug with UrlRewriteFilter. adding "/" to the  and  did the trick.

This is to final rule

```
<rule>
        <name>escaped_fragment</name>
        <!--<condition type="request-filename" operator="notfile"/>-->
        <condition type="query-string" operator="equal">.*escaped_fragment.*</condition>
        <from>^/(.*)$</from>
        <to type="proxy" last="true" qsappend="true">http://www.MY_SEO_SERVER.com/TOKEN_e291b9f78/$1</to>
    </rule>
```